# Ayuda con este error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5, sintaxis

Buenas me encuentro intentado llenar dos tablas de bases de datos relacionadas en Laravel empleando ajax

una de libros

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLibrosTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('libros', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('titulo');
        $table->integer('id_categoria')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('id_autor')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('id_editorial')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('cantidad');
        $table->date('fecha_lanzamiento');
        $table->string('idioma');
        $table->integer('paginas');
        $table->string('descripcion');
        $table->string('tipo');
        $table->string('enlace');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

y una de categorias

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriasTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categorias', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->integer('libro_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('libro_id')->references('id')->on('libros');


        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

y el scrip de AJAX

```
$("#registro").click(function()
{
var dato = $("#categoria").val();
var route = "http://localhost:8000/categoria";
var token = $("#token").val();

$.ajax({
    url: route,
    headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'json',
    data: {categoria: dato},

    success:function(){
        $("#msj-success").fadeIn();
    },

    error:function(msj){
        $("#msj").html(msj.responseJSON.categoria);
        $("#msj-error").fadeIn();
    }

});

});
```

a la hora de intentar llenarla la tabala categorias me sale el siguiente error:

**QueryException in Connection.php line 624: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`biblioteca`.`categorias`, CONSTRAINT `categorias_libro_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`libro_id`) REFERENCES `libros` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `categorias` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2017-01-05 19:06:28, 2017-01-05 19:06:28))**

si alguien puede identificar que estoy haciendo mal le agradeceria que lo mencionara

Answer (score 2):

Verifica la condición de la llave foránea, posiblemente estas tratando de grabar en la tabla detalle antes de grabar en la tabla principal.

Comment: disculpa no comprendo tu respuesta

Comment: Si hay 2 tablas 'A' y 'B', 'B' depende de 'A' por la llave foránea. Si 'A' no existe entonces 'B' no puede existir por la relación que tienen ambas tablas. En este caso puede ser que trates de ingresar un registro en una tabla "B", pero el campo en la tabla "A" al que lo quieres relacionar aun no existe.

Comment: ya entiendo probare a ver si funciona muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2):

Primero, creo que tienes la FK invertida. Un libro pertenece a una categoría, no a la inversa (a menos que fuera una relación many to manyque no es el caso).

Segundo, dada la relación de tu pregunta, no puedes insertar una categoría sin especificar el id del libro.

No sé específicamente cómo se hace en illuminate para establecer que el valor por defecto de libro_id sea NULL, lo cual permitiría insertar la categoría si  libro_id y sin violar la FK.