# Mostrar aviso al intentar borrar llave foranea LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo dos tablas con relación de uno a muchos, "Locaciones" y "Dispositivos", el problema surge a la hora de intentar borrar una "locación" que tiene un "dispositivo" relacionado, necesito que muestre un aviso que informe que la eliminación no se realizo y no el error SQLSTATE[23000], ¿Es posible capturar el error? esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
public function destroy(Location $location)
{
    try {
        //Eliminar registro
        $location->delete();
    } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        $status = 'Registro relacionado, imposible de eliminar';
    }
    //Retornar vista
    return redirect()->route('locations.index')
        ->with('status', $status);
}
```

Comment: Échale un vistazo a este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42653/ayuda-con-este-error-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-canno)

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, mi pregunta va mas a capturar el error y a partir de ello mostrar un aviso que enseñe que no se podrá  borrar por tener registros relacionados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo creo que no te está funcionando el *catch*, te faltaría la barra inclinada al principio. Te quedaría:

```
catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)
```

Una alternativa más corta sería:

```
catch (\Exception $e)
```

De resto, todo igual.

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el error, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Deber comprobar si existen registros en las tablas relacionadas, para ello puedes utilizar las relaciones de Eloquent, asumo que las tienes creadas.

Debería ser algo asi:

```
public function destroy(Location $location)
{
    $status='';
    $count=0;

    // Contamos los registros en las relaciones
    $count+=count($location->tabla1);
    $count+=count($location->tabla2);
    // Comprobamos si existen registros 
    if($count>0) {
        $status =  'Existen registros relacionados';
    } else {
        // si no hay registros eliminamos
        $location->delete();
        $status =  'Eliminado correctamente';
    }

    return redirect()->route('locations.index')
        ->with('status', $status);
}
```