# Unknown column 'servicio_independiente_id'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Estoy tratando de hace varios días de generar una relación de muchos a muchos en Laravel y no logro determinar donde está el problema o como solucionar el error.

Tengo la siguiente lógica de relación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla **Properties** ya la tenía creada: Necesitaba agregar servicios relacionados a las propiedades:

Por lo tanto cree la tabla **Servicio_Independientes** y la tabla intermedia **Independiente_property**.

**Servicio_Independientes**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('servicio_independientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('servicio')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreignId('tipodepropiedad_id')->references('id')->on('tipodepropiedad')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreignId('categorias_independientes_id')->references('id')->on('categorias_independientes')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

**Independiente_property**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('independiente_property', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->foreignId('servicio_independientes_id')->references('id')->on('servicio_independientes')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreignId('property_id')->references('id')->on('properties')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Y la relación en el **modelo Property**:

```
public function servicio_independientes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ServicioIndependiente', 'independiente_property', 'servicio_independientes_id');
    }
```

Y en el **modelo ServicioIndependiente**

```
public function properties(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class);
    }
```

Al guardar estos valores de la siguiente forma:

```
$properties->servicio_independientes()->attach($this->servicios);
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'servicio_independiente_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into
> `independiente_property` (`servicio_independiente_id`,
> `servicio_independientes_id`) values (1, 22), (3, 22), (4, 22), (5,
> 22), (11, 22))

Sé que tengo un lío con los nombres y las claves foraneas pero no encuentro la solución, agradezco mucho su tiempo destinado en mi consulta.

---

*******************EDICIÓN:*******************

Y de la siguiente manera:

```
public function servicio_independientes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(ServicioIndependiente::class, 'independiente_property', 'property_id', 'servicio_independientes_id');
    }
```

Recibo el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`brooklyn`.`independiente_property`, CONSTRAINT
> `independiente_property_servicio_independientes_id_foreign` FOREIGN
> KEY (`servicio_independientes_id`) REFERENCES
> `servicio_independientes` (`id) (SQL: insert into` independiente_property `(`property_id`,` servicio_independientes_id`)
> values (27, 1), (27, 3), (27, 4), (27, 5), (27, 0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si nos guiamos de la doc. de Laravel para la definición de relaciones en Eloquent en el apartado [`model estructure`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure) notarás que:

Los parámetros en el método `belongsToMany` son los siguientes:

- Modelo con el que se establece la relación
- Nombre de la tabla intermedia
- Llave foránea del modelo en el que estás definiendo la relación
- Llave foránea del modelo con el cual vincularás

Entonces esto:

```
$this->belongsToMany('App\ServicioIndependiente', 'independiente_property', 'servicio_independientes_id');
```

Debería pasar a esto:

```
$this->belongsToMany(ServicioIndependiente::class, 'independiente_property', 'property_id', 'servicio_independientes_id');
```

Comment: Lo había realizado de esa manera  y en la edición de la pregunta agregué el error que recibo. Creo que faltaría que agregue la llave foranea en los modelos puede ser?

Comment: @maraet te recomiendo para ese error leas por acá https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42653/ayuda-con-este-error-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-canno

Comment: Entiendo, pero una pregunta al momento de querer crear una propiedad quiero guardar los servicios seleccionados de la misma y en ese momento tendría que obtener el id de la propiedad y el id de los servicios para la tabla intermedia, no estaria obteniendo el id de la propiedad eso estaría dando el error?

Comment: No estaría entendiendo la solución, donde tendría que verificar? me puedes dar una mano más?

Comment: @maraet a lo que voy es que el mensaje de error que obtienes no tiene que ver o no es resultado de la configuración propuesta (*indicada por Laravel*), me daré un tiempo después para tratar de editar y explicar

Comment: Los servicios los tengo en multiples check los que no están seleccionados me los devuelve en false y ahí creo que tengo el problema, veo que cuando intenta realizar el el insert tiene un array asi: (27, 4), (27, 5), (27, 0) el ultimo es por que no se seleccionó nada y lo pone en false en el array y el error lo marca en 0. No sé si será eso.

Comment: Era eso, me ponía en false los checks no seleccionados y daba el error. De todas formas tu respuesta me ayudo mucho! muchas gracias!